# Just started C today, trying to understand obtaining values using fgets, sscanf and fscanf

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I have to understand someone else's code in C and I'm trying to understand how the variables are being defined using fgets, sscanf and fscanf.

input: ./test 0 testfile.txt

the code:

```
int main(argc,argv)
    int argc;
char *argv[];
{
char line[LINEBUF+1] //I assume this is where line type is 'defined'?
FILE *fopen(), *pfin ;
int   a, b;
char test_array[5]
```

...

```
pfin = stdin ;
fgets( line, LINEBUF, pfin);
sscanf(line," %s  %d", test_array,  &a)
fgets( line, LINEBUF, pfin);
fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",a);
```

It seems that this reads in the input ./test 0 testfile.txt, so a refers to 0. My questions are:

1. The value a is called in the end. So when using sscanf or fscan, do we just feed the address of any sort of input in, or are we using &a because it's an integer fed into fscan?
2. Why is fgets being used twice?
3. What do pfin and LINEBUF do?

This appears later in the code:

```
fgets( line, LINEBUF, pfin);
fscanf(pfin,"  b: %d", &b );
```

My question is:

4. I never saw b being given a value anywhere in the code until this section. Is this code taking content from within the file testfile.txt and giving value to variable b?

Comment: 4) This is what `fscanf` was designed to do

Comment: Where did you get this code from? I doesn't even compile.

Comment: Regarding `char line[LINEBUF+1]`, `line` is not a *type* but it is an *identifier*

Comment: If you started C today, I suggest chapter 1 of a primer, and the man pages for the functions you are asking about. 3. `pfin` is an unneccesary variable, you could use `stdin` directly instead; `LINEBUF` is an unshown macro defining the size of the buffer.

Comment: You can get a lot of help at SO but please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean this line is supposed to do: `FILE *fopen(), *pfin ;`?

Comment: The code I posted is just a snippet of the actual code.

Comment: @chipdash - yes, I can see that... but you should post code which is complete. Take your current code and delete everything not relevant for your question. Then post the rest. And (try to) make sure the code you post can compile. Example: I'm sure your code has something like `#define LINEBUF 500` but you didn't post that.

Comment: Ah, good ol' K&R! The lines are quite similar to https://github.com/kern-lab/shIC/blob/master/niceStats.c , if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(argc,argv)
    int argc;
    char *argv[];
{
   ...
```

This is a very archaic style of defining function parameters, and should not be used in new code anymore (it's been out of date since the late 1980s); instead, it should be written

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{
   ...
```

> The value a is called in the end. So when using sscanf or fscan, do we just feed the address of any sort of input in, or are we using &a because it's an integer fed into fscan?

Each conversion specifier (`%s`, `%d`, `%f`, etc.) expects the corresponding argument to have the correct type.  In the line

```
sscanf(line," %s  %d", test_array,  &a)
```

`%s` expects its corresponding argument, `test_array`, to have type `char *`, and `%d` expects its corresponding argument, `&a`, to have type `int *`.  Fortunately the arguments are the right type<sup>1</sup>, so everything should work.  Note that conversion specifiers have different meanings for `*scanf` and `*printf`.  Where `%d` expects an `int *` for `*scanf`, it expects a plain `int` for `*printf`.

> Why is fgets being used twice?

You don't provide enough code to answer this question.  It looks like the code is reading each input line as text (using `fgets`) and then parsing data from that line (using `sscanf`).  Based on the limited snippet you've posted, it's expecting at least the first part of the input to be structured such that you have one line with a short string (max 4 characters long) followed by an integer, something like

```
AAAA 10
```

Since you don't show how `line` is processed after that, it's anybody's guess what it's supposed to contain.

> What do pfin and LINEBUF do?

`pfin` is being set to point to the standard input stream; honestly, it's superfluous, and you can use the built-in variable `stdin` in its place.

`LINEBUF` is a macro that expands to either an integer literal or an integer expression, and it's being used to specify the size of the `line` array.  An example would be

```
#define LINEBUF 100
...
char line[LINEBUF + 1];
```

After preprocessing, the above code becomes

```
char line[100 + 1];
```

Remember that in C, a *string* is a sequence of character values followed by a 0-valued *terminator* value.  Thus, to store a *n*-character string, you need to set aside a *n*+1-element array of char.

---

1. The expression `a` has type `int`, so the expression `&a` has type `int *`.  The expression `test_array` has type `char [5]`; under most circumstances, an array expression will be converted ("decay") to a pointer expression, and the value of the pointer expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  This implicit converion *only* applies to arrays.